# Increasing efficiency of a string filter

Tags: python, python-3.x, performance, filter

I have a long text file containing a number of strings. Here is the part of the file:

```
tyh89= 13
kb2= 0
78%= yes
##@bb1= 7634.0
iih54= 121
fgddd= no
#aa1= 0
#aa2= 1
#$ac3= 0
yt#@hh= 0
#j= 12.1
##hf= no
```

So, basically all elements have a common structure of: `header= value`. My goal is to search for elements, whose headers contain specific string parts and read out those elements' values.

A the moment I do it with a rather straight approach: open/read the whole file as a string, differentiate it into list of elements and run if/elif conditions over all elements using a for loop. I provide my code below.

**Is it the most efficient way to do it? Or is there a more efficient way to do it with not implementing the loop?**

```
def main():
    print(list(import_param()))

def import_param():
    fl = open('filename','r')
    cn = fl.read()
    cn = cn.split('\n')
    fl.close()
    for st in cn:
        if 'fgddd' in st:
            el = st.split(' ')
            yield float(el[1])
        elif '#j' in st:
            el = st.split(' ')
            yield float(el[1])    

if __name__ == '__main__': main()
```

Answer (score 2):

yes, there is. You have to avoid testing if string contains a string, but rather focus on string *equality*.

Once you settle for equality, it means that you can create a set with the known keywords, split according to `=` and test if the set contains your value (using `O(1)` lookup):

```
key_set = {"fgddd","#j"}

for st in cn:
    if '=' in st:
       key,value = st.split("=",1)
       if key in key_set:
           el = value.strip()
           yield float(el)
```

if you have different types, use a dictionary to convert to the proper type according to the key

```
key_set = {"fgddd":float ,"#j": float, "whatever":int , "something":str}

for st in cn:
    if '=' in st:
       key,value = st.split("=",1)
       if key in key_set:
           el = value.strip()
           yield key_set[key](el)  # apply type conversion
```

note that if you don't want any conversion, `str` will do the job as it returns itself when passed a string.

final note: if you have a say on the input format, suggest to use `json` instead of a custom format. Parsing becomes trivial using `json` module, and filtering can be achieved by the same way I've shown.

Comment: It helps to organise together all of the testing statements. But it still includes looping over the whole list elements one by one. Is it the only way?